# Problems using drupal / console

Tags: console, drupal-8

I installed Drupal Console Launcher as described in the documentation :

```
curl https://drupalconsole.com/installer -L -o drupal.phar
mv drupal.phar /usr/local/bin/drupal
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drupal
```

It works fine and the 'drupal' command works.

After I installed the console in the site folder :

```
composer.phar require drupal/console:~1.0 \
--prefer-dist \
--optimize-autoloader
```

When I run the 'drupal list' command in the site folder I have a message : `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

So I edited the 'host' in the 'settings.php' file replacing 'localhost' for '127.0.0.1'

In this case, I have a `SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error and the site no longer works!

I also tried installing drupal 8 with Composer to have the console. There I have an error `SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

It's been almost a week now that I try in all directions without success!

I'm on OSX with a MAMP server.

Would anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you verify that your mysql server is up and running and configured to be accessed by drupal?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I normally access my local installation. But if you think of something else I do not know how we do to know if mysql is configured properly.

Comment: Try to log in into mysql client and check databases and user configurations to verify mysql is functioning properly. After that check this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/database-configuration).

Comment: There is a https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/drupal_console_faq/installation-problems.html which helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the links that helped me solve the exact same problem:

Working with Drush on MAMP https://www.drupal.org/node/1651282
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/180924

https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/drupal_console_faq/installation-problems.html

The problem is that I am hosting the site and database with MAMP on mac OS, but Drupal Console and Drush use the terminal, thus the system's PHP version and MySQL socket. Not the one from MAMP. So any article explaning how to make Drupal Console or Drush work with MAMP can be useful.

In my case, the only thing missing if I'm not mistaken was a symbolik link on MAMP's mysql socket

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But the articles above also show us how to use MAMP's default PHP version from the terminal and other things good to know!